# Create a folder in Web Project?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, directory

My web project is Tomcat+ jsp.  When I try to create a folder in this project, there is no exception in my code and always show folder exists. However, I can't find the folder from the directory.

My code is as follows:

```
private static final String imagFolder="pictures";
private static final String Separator=java.io.File.separator;
String directory = request.getContextPath()+Separator+imagFolder;
CreateFileUtil.createDir(directory);
```

*******CreateFileUtil.createDir***************************************

```
public static  boolean createDir( String destDirName) {
    File dir = new File(destDirName);
    if (dir.exists()) {// in this line,there is not exception and return true however, when I check the direcotry ,there folder doesn't exists
        System.out.println("create directory" + destDirName + "Failure, it already exists");
        return false;
    }
    if (!destDirName.endsWith(File.separator)) {
        destDirName = destDirName + File.separator;
    }
    //create
    if (dir.mkdirs()) {
        System.out.println("create directory" + destDirName + "Success");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("create directory" + destDirName + "Failure");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, The problem is sovled.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem is solved.

I just change the code:

```
String directory = request.getContextPath()+Separator+imagFolder;
```

into

```
 String directory=  request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+Separator+imagFolder;
```

Then it success.